# Can a puzzle have a CC licence added?

Tags: discussion, support

Let me address my intention. I want to ensure that if reproduced a complete unaltered copy of the puzzle is required and a correct reference to this original puzzle must be included so, if not prohibited by Puzzling.SE terms I want to include the following licence on [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62588/who-can-solve-this-cipher).

[image: Creative Commons License]
Who can solve this cipher? by  [Willtech](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/62588/who-can-solve-this-cipher) is licensed under a [Creative Commons Attribution-NoDerivatives 4.0 International License](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/4.0/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry, but that is not possible. Under the [terms of service](https://stackexchange.com/legal) (which you clearly read before signing up, since everyone actually reads those, right?), you implicitly agree to license everything you submit to Stack Exchange under a Creative Commons Attribution Share-Alike license.

The good news is this does mean that everyone using it must include a reference to the original puzzle, but derivative works are allowed.

Comment: Was just typing that. Beat me to it. (See also, the footer of every page.)